# fail to git push and can't load github.com

Tags: git, github

This is the mistake:

```
➜  leetcodebypython git:(master) git push
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After I have run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
git config --local -e
```

change entry of url from

```
git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

to

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Also my chrome have the warning with "not safe" when loading https://github.com

How to manage it?

Comment: It's strange, what are you trying to do exactly? Configure a git repository remotely? Anyway what gives `git config --list`?

Comment: Focus your SO questions to a single issue per question. The "not safe" warning in Google Chrome is a different issue, likely having to do with your DNS settings. Edit your question to remove that portion so you focus this question on connecting your local git repository to your remote GitHub repository.

Answer (score 2):

Your remote git URL is incorrect; the general format of the SSH URLs is:

```
git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

and the general format of the HTTPS URLs is:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

where `username` is either a person or an organization, and `repo` is the repository you're connecting to, e.g., if your repository is `hello-world` and your GitHub username is `bigbugboy` then the SSH repository URL is:

```
git@github.com:bigbugboy/hello-world.git
```

To get started with GitHub, you will likely find it easier if you [login to your GitHub account](https://github.com/login), create a new repository with the UI, get the SSH URL from the UI, and use that URL to clone your repository locally, e.g.:

```
git clone git@github.com:bigbugboy/hello-world-again.git
```

When you use the git protocol in your repository URL, git handles the SSH connection details so you don't use ssh directly; you just use git. But before you can push your updates to your GitHub repository via SSH, you have to [add your SSH key(s) to your account in GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) which is done in your GitHub account settings under "SSH and GPG key".

Comment: *the general format of the HTTPS URLs is: `https://github.com:username/repo.git`* No it's `https://github.com/username/repo.git` (slash, not colon)!